# I have a CPU leak in a TKinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python program using TKinter as a GUI. it´s a chess board for an specific purpose, it counts how many white and black pieces are touching every square on the board according with chess rules, I call them shadows.

Around the 21st time it executes "captura" command pushing the button "boton", the CPU go to 100% and the program behavies out of the window and should be dropped.

I showed all the executable code because I don´t know where the CPU leak could be. What I have done is:

- I already review the number of instances for the two Classes: Tablero (board) there is just one instance of Tablero and the other Class Pieza (piece) there is only 32 instances, so it´s not creating more instances
- I printed the list of objects and their atributes and the all the matrices every time it calculates everything again, and the calculations are ok

So my hypothesis is that something is wrong with TKinter at the moment it presents the pieces and shadows on the board..

I appreciate your comments. Any doubt, please let me know.

Kind regards,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import operator
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk        
'''
Created on 30 oct 2021
@author: HQ
'''

# creación de matrices 
tablero = []
shadow_blancas = []
shadow_negras = []
piezas_blancas = []
piezas_negras = []
i_piezas_blancas = []
i_piezas_negras = []
letras = []

# class board
class i_tablero:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master = master
        self.panedwindow = ttk.Panedwindow(self.master, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.panedwindow.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.panedwindow, width = 300, height = 740, relief = SUNKEN)
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.panedwindow, width = 740, height = 740, relief = SUNKEN)
        self.panedwindow.add(self.frame1)
        self.panedwindow.add(self.frame2)
        
        self.labeldesde = ttk.Label(self.frame1, text = "desde")
        
        self.varl1 = StringVar()
        self.combol1= ttk.Combobox(self.frame1, textvariable = self.varl1, width = 10)
        self.combol1.config(values = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), width = 10)
        #self.varl1.set("A")

        self.varn1 = StringVar()
        self.combon1= ttk.Combobox(self.frame1, textvariable = self.varn1, width = 10)
        self.combon1.config(values = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), width = 10)
        #self.varn1.set("1")

        self.labelhacia = ttk.Label(self.frame1, text = "hacia")
        
        self.varl2 = StringVar()
        self.combol2= ttk.Combobox(self.frame1, textvariable = self.varl2, width = 10)
        self.combol2.config(values = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), width = 10)
        #self.varl2.set("A")

        self.varn2 = StringVar()
        self.combon2= ttk.Combobox(self.frame1, textvariable = self.varn2, width = 10)
        self.combon2.config(values = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), width = 10)
        self.varn2.set("1")

        # at the 21st time the program execute captura, the CPU raises to 100% and the program is out of control
        self.boton = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text = "calcula", command= self.captura)

        # pinta campos
        self.labeldesde.place(x = 50, y = 75)
        self.combol1.place(x = 50, y = 100)
        self.combon1.place(x = 160, y = 100)
        self.labelhacia.place(x = 50, y = 125)
        self.combol2.place(x = 50, y = 150)
        self.combon2.place(x = 160, y = 150)
        self.boton.place(x= 105, y = 200)

        self.bg_color = []
        for t in range(8):
            self.bg_color.append([0] * 8)
        set_color = "white"
        for h in range(8):
            if set_color == "white":
                set_color = "green"
            else:
                set_color = "white"
            for q in range(8):
                self.bg_color[h][q]= set_color
                if set_color == "white":
                    set_color = "green"
                else:
                    set_color = "white"

    def pinta_tablero(self):
        xx = 50
        yy = 50
        bck = "green"
        wihe = 80
        for j in range(8):
            xx = 50
            if bck == "green":
                bck = "white"
            else:
                bck = "green"
            for i in range(8):
                ttk.Label(self.frame2, background = bck).place(x = xx, y = yy, width = wihe, height = wihe)
                if bck == "green":
                    bck = "white"
                else:
                    bck = "green"
                xx += 80
            yy += 80
            
        letrass = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
        numeross = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
        x1 = 86
        y1a = 20
        y1b = 710
        for k in range(8):
            ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = letrass[k]).place(x = x1, y = y1a)
            ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = letrass[k]).place(x = x1, y = y1b)
        
            ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = numeross[7-k]).place(x = y1a, y = x1)
            ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = numeross[7-k]).place(x = y1b, y = x1)
        
            x1 += 80

    def pinta_pieza(self, o, im):
        vx = [60, 140, 220, 300, 380, 460, 540, 620]
        vy = [620, 540, 460, 380, 300, 220, 140, 60]

        # x son columnas, y son renglones
        c = o.get_posCol()
        r = o.get_posRow()
        ttk.Label(self.frame2, image = im, background = self.bg_color[r][c]).place(x = vx[c], y = vy[r])

    # Shadow is the purpose of the program, it means how many white and black pieces are touching each square on the board
    def pinta_shadow(self):
        vx = [50, 130, 210, 290, 370, 450, 530, 610]
        vy = [610, 530, 450, 370, 290, 210, 130, 50]

        for ib in range(8):
            for jb in range(8):
                if shadow_blancas[jb][ib] == 0:
                    ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = " ", background= self.bg_color[ib][jb]).place(x = vx[ib]+66, y = vy[jb])
                else:
                    ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = shadow_blancas[jb][ib], font = ('Arial', 11, "bold"), foreground = "orange", background= self.bg_color[ib][jb]).place(x = vx[ib]+66, y = vy[jb])


        for nn in range(8):
            for jn in range(8):
                if shadow_negras[jn][nn] == 0:
                    ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = " ", background= self.bg_color[nn][jn]).place(x = vx[nn]+2, y = vy[jn])
                else:
                    ttk.Label(self.frame2, text = shadow_negras[jn][nn], font = ('Arial', 11, "bold"), background= self.bg_color[nn][jn]).place(x = vx[nn]+2, y = vy[jn])

    def borraPieza(self):
        newRow = int(self.comboJ1.get())-1
        newCol = letras.get(self.comboI1.get())
        self.borra_pieza(newRow, newCol)
    
    def borra_pieza(self, newRow, newCol):
        mij = 99    
        for o in piezas_blancas:
            if o.get_posRow() == newRow and o.get_posCol() == newCol:
                mij = piezas_blancas.index(o) 
                self.borra_pieza_blanca(mij)
                    
        for o in piezas_negras:
            if o.get_posRow() == newRow and o.get_posCol() == newCol:
                mij = piezas_negras.index(o)
                self.borra_pieza_negra(mij)
    
    def borra_pieza_blanca(self, mij):
        del piezas_blancas[mij]
        self.pinta_tablero()
        self.calcula_todo()
    
    def borra_pieza_negra(self, mij):
        del piezas_negras[mij]
        self.pinta_tablero()
        self.calcula_todo()

    def captura(self):
        dl1 = self.combol1.get()
        dn1 = self.combon1.get()
        dl2 = self.combol2.get()
        dn2 = self.combon2.get()
        mcaptura = 99
        newRow = int(dn2)-1
        newCol = letras.get(dl2)
        myRow = int(dn1)-1
        myCol = letras.get(dl1)
    
        # Captura should call borra_pieza (delete piece) first, in case the piece moved is taking another from the oposite player
        self.borra_pieza(newRow, newCol)
    
        # Now it´s time to move its own
        for o in piezas_blancas:
            if o.get_posRow() == myRow and o.get_posCol() == myCol:
                mcaptura = piezas_blancas.index(o) 
                self.cambia_posicion(piezas_blancas[mcaptura],newRow, newCol)
                    
        for o in piezas_negras:
            if o.get_posRow() == myRow and o.get_posCol() == myCol:
                mcaptura = piezas_negras.index(o)
                self.cambia_posicion(piezas_negras[mcaptura],newRow, newCol)
        
        self.pinta_tablero()
        self.calcula_todo()
        
    def cambia_posicion(self, o, newRow, newCol):
        o._posRow = newRow
        o._posCol = newCol
    
    def calcula_todo(self):
        inicializa_tableros(tablero, shadow_blancas, shadow_negras)
                       
        # asigna piezas al tablero
        for o in piezas_blancas:
            o.posicion()
        for o in piezas_negras:
            o.posicion()

        # Calcula shadows 
        for o in piezas_blancas:
            o.calcula_shadow()
        for o in piezas_negras:
            o.calcula_shadow()
        
        for k in piezas_blancas:
            tipo = k.get_tipo()
            if tipo[-1] == "K":
                i_pas = i_piezas_blancas[0]
            elif tipo[-1] == "Q":
                i_pas = i_piezas_blancas[1]
            elif tipo[-1] == "R":
                i_pas = i_piezas_blancas[2]
            elif tipo[-1] == "N":
                i_pas = i_piezas_blancas[3]
            elif tipo[-1] == "B":
                i_pas = i_piezas_blancas[4]
            else:
                i_pas = i_piezas_blancas[5]
            self.pinta_pieza(k, i_pas)
    
        for k in piezas_negras:
            tipo = k.get_tipo()
            if tipo[-1] == "K":
                i_pas = i_piezas_negras[0]
            elif tipo[-1] == "Q":
                i_pas = i_piezas_negras[1]
            elif tipo[-1] == "R":
                i_pas = i_piezas_negras[2]
            elif tipo[-1] == "N":
                i_pas = i_piezas_negras[3]
            elif tipo[-1] == "B":
                i_pas = i_piezas_negras[4]
            else:
                i_pas = i_piezas_negras[5]
            self.pinta_pieza(k, i_pas)
        self.pinta_shadow()

def crea_tableros(tablero, shadow_blancas, shadow_negras): 
    for i in range(8):
        tablero.append([0] * 8)
        shadow_blancas.append([0] * 8)
        shadow_negras.append([0] * 8)

def inicializa_tableros(tablero, shadow_blancas, shadow_negras):    
    # Crea tablero 8x8
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            tablero[i][j] = "  "
            shadow_blancas[i][j] = 0
            shadow_negras[i][j] = 0

class Pieza:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'nombre' in kwargs: self._nombre = kwargs['nombre']
        if 'tipo' in kwargs: self._tipo = kwargs['tipo']
        if 'posCol' in kwargs: self._posCol = kwargs['posCol']
        if 'posRow' in kwargs: self._posRow = kwargs['posRow']

    def get_nombre(self, t = None):
        if t: self._nombre = t
        try: return self._nombre
        except AttributeError: return None
        
    def get_tipo(self, t = None):
        if t: self._tipo = t
        try: return self._tipo
        except AttributeError: return None

    def get_posCol(self, t = None):
        if t: self._posCol = t
        try: return self._posCol
        except AttributeError: return None

    def get_posRow(self, t = None):
        if t: self._posRow = t
        try: return self._posRow
        except AttributeError: return None

    def posicion(self):
        row = self.get_posRow()
        col = self.get_posCol()
        tablero[row] [col] = self.get_tipo()

    def calcula_shadow(self):
        r = self.get_posRow()
        c = self.get_posCol()
        paso = self.get_tipo()
        wb = paso[0]

        if self.get_tipo() == "WB" or self.get_tipo() == "BB":
            # iteraciones Bishop         
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, wb)

        if self.get_tipo() == "WR" or  self.get_tipo() == "BR":
            # Iteracoines Rook         
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1,  c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 0, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 0, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 0, wb )
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 0, c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, wb )

        if self.get_tipo() == "WQ" or self.get_tipo() == "BQ":
            # Iteraciones Queen         
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1,  c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1,  c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 0, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 0, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 1, c, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 0, wb)
            self.calcula_altore(r, operator.isub, operator.ge, 0, 0, c, operator.iadd, operator.le, 7, 1, wb)

        if self.get_tipo() == "WN" or self.get_tipo() == "BN":
            # Iteraciones Knight
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 1, c, operator.add, 2, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 2, c, operator.add, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 2, c, operator.sub, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 1, c, operator.sub, 2, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 1, c, operator.sub, 2, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 2, c, operator.sub, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 2, c, operator.add, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 1, c, operator.add, 2, wb)
            
        if self.get_tipo() == "WK" or self.get_tipo() == "BK":
            # iteraciones King
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 1, c, operator.add, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 1, c, operator.add, 0, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 1, c, operator.sub, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 0, c, operator.sub, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 1, c, operator.sub, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 1, c, operator.sub, 0, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 1, c, operator.add, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 0, c, operator.add, 1, wb)
            
        if self.get_tipo() == "WP":
            # Iteraciones White Pawn
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 1, c, operator.add, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.add, 1, c, operator.sub, 1, wb)

        if self.get_tipo() == "BP":
            # Iteraciones Black Pawn
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 1, c, operator.sub, 1, wb)
            self.calcula_carey(r,operator.sub, 1, c, operator.add, 1, wb)

    def calcula_carey(self, r,operadorr, r1, c, operadorc, c1, wb): 
        r = operadorr(r, r1)
        c = operadorc(c, c1)
        wb1 = wb
        if r >= 0 and r <=7 and c >=0 and c <= 7:
            self.contador_shadow(wb1, r, c)
        
    def calcula_altore(self, r, opr, operadorr, limr, incrr, c, opc, operadorc, limc, incrc, wb):        
        r = opr(r, incrr)
        c = opc(c, incrc)
        wb1 = wb 
        
        if operadorr(r, limr) and operadorc(c, limc):
            fl = True
            while fl:
                self.contador_shadow(wb1, r, c)
                tope = tablero[r][c]
                if tope[0] == "W" or tope[0] == "B":
                    fl = False
                else:
                    r = opr(r, incrr)
                    c = opc(c, incrc)
                    if operadorr(r, limr) and operadorc(c, limc):
                        fl = True 
                    else:
                        fl = False   
          
    def contador_shadow(self, wb1, r, c):
        if wb1 == "W":
            shadow_blancas[r][c] += 1
        else:
            shadow_negras[r][c] += 1 

# crea instancia de tablero
root = Tk()
i_t = i_tablero(root)
i_t.pinta_tablero()

# Inicializa tableros
crea_tableros(tablero, shadow_blancas, shadow_negras)
inicializa_tableros(tablero, shadow_blancas, shadow_negras)
    
letras = dict(A=0, B=1, C=2, D=3, E=4, F=5, G=6, H=7)
    
# Crea las piezas blancas
wp1 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn1", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 0)
wp2 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn2", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 1)
wp3 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn3", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 2)
wp4 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn4", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 3)
wp5 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn5", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 4)
wp6 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn6", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 5)
wp7 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn7", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 6)
wp8 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn8", tipo = "WP", posRow = 1, posCol = 7)
wrq = Pieza(nombre = "RookQ", tipo = "WR", posRow = 0, posCol = 0)
wnq = Pieza(nombre = "KnightQ", tipo = "WN", posRow = 0, posCol = 1)
wbq = Pieza(nombre = "BishopQ", tipo = "WB" , posRow = 0, posCol = 2)
wq = Pieza(nombre = "Queen", tipo = "WQ", posRow = 0, posCol = 3)
wk = Pieza(nombre = "King", tipo = "WK", posRow = 0, posCol = 4)
wbk = Pieza(nombre = "BishopK", tipo = "WB", posRow = 0, posCol = 5)
wnk = Pieza(nombre = "KnightK", tipo = "WN", posRow = 0, posCol = 6)
wrk = Pieza(nombre = "RookK", tipo = "WR", posRow = 0, posCol = 7)
# Crea el arreglo de piezas negras
bp1 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn1", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 0)
bp2 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn2", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 1)
bp3 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn3", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 2)
bp4 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn4", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 3)
bp5 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn5", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 4)
bp6 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn6", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 5)
bp7 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn7", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 6)
bp8 = Pieza(nombre = "Pawn8", tipo = "BP", posRow = 6, posCol = 7)
brq = Pieza(nombre = "RookQ", tipo = "BR", posRow = 7, posCol = 0)
bnq = Pieza(nombre = "KnightQ", tipo = "BN", posRow = 7, posCol = 1)
bbq = Pieza(nombre = "BishopQ", tipo = "BB" , posRow = 7, posCol = 2)
bq = Pieza(nombre = "Queen", tipo = "BQ", posRow = 7, posCol = 3)
bk = Pieza(nombre = "King", tipo = "BK", posRow = 7, posCol = 4)
bbk = Pieza(nombre = "BishopK", tipo = "BB", posRow = 7, posCol = 5)
bnk = Pieza(nombre = "KnightK", tipo = "BN", posRow = 7, posCol = 6)
brk = Pieza(nombre = "RookK", tipo = "BR", posRow = 7, posCol = 7)

# Crea el arreglo de piezas blancas y negras
piezas_blancas = [wp1, wp2, wp3, wp4, wp5, wp6, wp7, wp8, wrq, wnq, wbq, wq, wk, wbk, wnk, wrk]
piezas_negras = [bp1, bp2, bp3, bp4, bp5, bp6, bp7, bp8, brq, bnq, bbq, bq, bk, bbk, bnk, brk]

# Inicializa imagenes
i_wk = PhotoImage(file = "i_rey_blanco_60.png")
i_wq = PhotoImage(file = "i_reyna_blanca_60.png")
i_wr = PhotoImage(file = "i_torre_blanca_60.png")
i_wn = PhotoImage(file = "i_caballo_blanco_60.png")
i_wb = PhotoImage(file = "i_alfil_blanco_60.png")
i_wp = PhotoImage(file = "i_peon_blanco_60.png")
   
i_bk = PhotoImage(file = "i_rey_negro_60.png")
i_bq = PhotoImage(file = "i_reyna_negra_60.png")
i_br = PhotoImage(file = "i_torre_negra_60.png")
i_bn = PhotoImage(file = "i_caballo_negro_60.png")
i_bb = PhotoImage(file = "i_alfil_negro_60.png")
i_bp = PhotoImage(file = "i_peon_negro_60.png")

# crea el arreglo de imágenes para piezas blancas y negras    
i_piezas_blancas = [i_wk, i_wq, i_wr, i_wn, i_wb, i_wp]
i_piezas_negras = [i_bk, i_bq, i_br, i_bn, i_bb, i_bp]

i_t.calcula_todo()

# Pasa control al tablero
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Every time you call `.pinta_shadow()`, you're creating 128 new Label objects, *that never get removed from the window* - they just pile up in memory, forever.

Comment: Got it Jason, then, instead of creating new objects with .Label, should I name them and then use .configure? that way I will avoid creating a bunch of objects? thanks a lot for your comments and advices